# Redirect + rewrite infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Im sorry, my english is not very good but I'll try to explain my question.
So. 'index.php' is my main landing page.

A. Every request should go to index.php.
Its easy.`RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`(simplified).
So when I write 'News/123' in addr bar then index.php will handle it and show me the news. It works fine.

B. But I also need to make '/index.php' entered in addr bar to be replaced by '/Home' and then -> A. I thought it can be done by `Redirect /index.php /Main` but it causes an infinite redirection loop.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /home [L,R=302]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. As I understand key of profit here is R=302 which make address change by redirecting?

Comment: Yes that's correct and `%{THE_REQUEST}` is the original request received by Apache.